# Java - Pausing a method?

Tags: java, sleep

one of my menus is simply an image, and a button to go 'back.'
The problem is, the back button always loads *before* the image, even though it is after in the code.

Is there any way to fix this? I'm brand new to programming, so the best way I could think of would be to pause the method somehow, say for 3 seconds, while the picture loads, THEN load the back button.

I have tried using thread.sleep(3000) but if I do that, the image doesn't load at all! Maybe I am using it wrong?

```
public void render(Graphics g){

 if(Instscrn==true){
        g.drawImage(InstructionScreen, 0, 0, Resources.sp);

        if(instclose){
            g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 30)); 
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.drawString("Back", 672, 552);
        }
```

With thread.sleep

```
public void render(Graphics g){

 if(Instscrn==true){
        g.drawImage(InstructionScreen, 0, 0, Resources.sp);

       try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(instclose){
            g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 30)); 
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.drawString("Back", 672, 552);
        }
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should never introduce lags for displays. You're then limiting how fast things could potentially run.

Comment: Is there a different way?

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of what is being rendered to the screen? I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "before the image"... Is it being hidden?? An image would be useful.

Comment: You shouldn't rely on execution breaks. Your timeout could have no effect on very fast machines.

Answer (score 1):

You can load image on render(Graphics g) without pausing any method:

```
boolean inited = false;
Image i;
public void render(Graphics g){
    if(!inited) {
        //here, init your image, for example: download files from web or load resources
        try {
            i = ImageIO.read(new File(""));//loading image
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();//error
        } 
        inited=true;
    }
    g.drawImage...
}
```

You can't pause a method, but you can pause a thread (with method):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    final Thread pauseable = new Thread("Pauseable method/thread") {
        //Pauseable method
        public void run() {
            for(int i=0; i<20; i++) {
                System.out.println("Working");
                sleepMethod();
            }
        }
        //Sleep for 1 seconds
        public void sleepMethod() {
            try {
                sleep(1000);
            } catch(Throwable t){}
        }
    };
    pauseable.start();
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    JButton pause = new JButton("Pause");
    JButton start = new JButton("Resume");
    pause.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            try {
                pauseable.suspend();
            } catch(Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        }});
    start.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            try {
                pauseable.resume();
            } catch(Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        }});

    //STYLE OF BUTTONS ETC.:
    JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2));
    p.add(pause);
    p.add(start);
    f.getContentPane().add(p);
    f.pack();
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);


    pauseable.join(); //If you want wait to end of running method
    System.out.println("Method pauseable.run() was ended!");
}
```